# Get webpage element -> return element + css style -> render element locally?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-requests

[image]

I want to render a single webpage element ***locally***. Lets use the example of the google search bar above....

I can use python-requests or bs4 to return the element and its attributes easily enough. Element HTML shown below:

```
<input class="gLFyf gsfi" maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text" jsaction="paste:puy29d" 
aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" 
autofocus="" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" title="Search" value="" aria-label="Search" 
data-ved="0ahUKEwjj48bGtL_tAhW9yzgGHbDdBmMQ39UDCAU">
```

## Question

Now that I have this element:

- How can I also return its computed style? (What it looks like)
- I want to do this programmatically (ie via Python (ideally) or JS)

Why? I want to be able to recreate the element EXACTLY as it is shown/looks on google.com, but in a local HTML file. Positions etc don't matter however.

***I do not want to use Selenium or any other complete browser tool***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an element in its style, you'll have to import all CSS on the page.

So you'd want to do a GET requests and parse it with BS4, then grep all the `<style>` tags on the page, and then add a `<base href>` tag to change the base URL on the page to Google (so that relative links will still work).

Comment: Thanks @isopach that seems to be the best approach